# Using a value from one query in second query sql

Tags: sql

```
SELECT AS, COUNT(*)
FROM Table1
HAVING COUNT(AS)>1
group BY AS;
```

This produces the result

```
AS      COUNT
5       2
```

I then want to use the AS value in another query and only output the end result. Is this possible.i was thinking something like.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
TABLE 2 
Where AS =(
           SELECT AS, COUNT(*)
           FROM Table1
           HAVING COUNT(AS)>1
           group BY AS;
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a subquery.  To be safe, you would use `in` instead of `=` (and `as` is a bad name for a column, because it is a SQL key word):

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE2 
WHERE col IN (SELECT col
              FROM Table1
              GROUP BY col
              HAVING COUNT(col) > 1
             );
```

Your first query is also incorrect, because the `having` clause goes after the `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subquery with the `in` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table2
WHERE  AS IN (SELECT   AS
              FROM     table1
              GROUP BY AS
              HAVING   COUNT(*) > 1)
```